# How to get the code formatter to not indent try/except blocks

Tags: delphi, formatter

Using Delphi 10.2.3, I've got the code formatter set up the way I want it, with one exception: while it formats `if-then begin/end` blocks without adding a line break before the `begin` or adding extra indention, the same is not true for `if-then try/except` blocks - it both adds a line break before the `try`, and indents the entire `try/except` block by my defined spacing.  In other words...

What I want is this:

```
  if MyBool1 then begin
    CallProc1;
  end;
  //...
  if MyBool2 then try
    CallProc2;
  except
    //...
  end;
```

What I get is this:

```
  if MyBool1 then begin
    CallProc1;
  end;
  //...
  if MyBool2 then 
    try
      CallProc2;
    except
      //...
    end;
```

I assume I'm just missing some setting, but I can't determine which one.  What am I missing?